# Multiple sbt projects with the same root

Tags: scala, sbt

I want multiple sbt projects with the exact same root so I can build the same code with different settings. I've tried something similar to what I have below, but sbt only recognizes the first project (`root`).

```
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Scala Seed Project",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
  )

lazy val root2 = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Scala Seed Project",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
  )
```

Comment: I guess the different settings are not just the Scala version?

Comment: Otherwise SBT supports it natively or plugin like _sbt-projectmatrix_ could help you'

Comment: @GaëlJ Correct, I just threw the Scala version is an example. I also need different dependency versions and potentially other changes. It looks like sbt-projectmatrix may work. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer, but I found the suggestion below on [this page](https://www.joekearney.co.uk/posts/sbt-two-artifacts-one-source) which does seem to work for this simple example.

```
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val root = (project in file("target/root"))
  .settings(
    name := "Scala Seed Project",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.6",
    Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / ".." / ".." / "src" / "main" / "scala",
  )

lazy val root2 = (project in file("target/root2"))
  .settings(
    name := "Scala Seed Project",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.12",
    Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / ".." / ".." / "src" / "main" / "scala",
  )
```

I don't love this solution because it requires dummy directories and an otherwise unnecessary redefinition of `scalaSource` for multiple tasks (although I've only included compilation in the example above).